# Place an ajax request in a button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a quiz and answers for the question are buttons.

I have a JSON database and I can request a part of that database (in this example its "answerA") and place it into a div tag. The code for request is like this:

```
function ajax_get_json(){
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "question_database.json", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            var results = document.getElementById("results");
            results.innerHTML = data.stuff[0].AnswerA;
        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
    results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}
```

Now, placing the result in the div is like this and works perfectly:

```
<div id="results"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">ajax_get_json();</script>
```

But what I would like to do is to place the result in the value of the button:

```
<input type="submit" class="answerButton" data-role="none" value="I'd like to place it here" />
```

Is there anyway how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: `$('.answerButton').val(data.stuff[0].AnswerA)`

Comment: @RayonDabre Looks as if OP is after a solution without jQuery.

Comment: But `jQ` is tagged! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or in pure js:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('answerButton')[0];
button.value = data.stuff[0].AnswerA;
```

But you better set id to this button.

Answer (score 0):

just simply set id for button and then use same as for div tag ,instead of innerhtml use value

```
        var results = document.getElementById("button_id");
        results.value = data.stuff[0].AnswerA;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using `jQuery`, `.val()` will set the value of every matched element.

```
$('.answerButton').val(data.stuff[0].AnswerA);
```

> To update only first matched element:

```
$('.answerButton:first').val(data.stuff[0].AnswerA);
```

> Using `JavaScript`, you can use `element.value=` or `setAttribute`. `querySelector` will return only one element which matches the selector.

```
document.querySelector('.answerButton').value=data.stuff[0].AnswerA;
```

**OR**

```
document.querySelector('.answerButton').setAttribute('value' ,data.stuff[0].AnswerA);
```

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in many ways but seems you does not have id to your submit button so you can use class like below

```
var elmts = document.getElementsByClass("answerButton");
elmts[0].value = data.stuff[0].AnswerA;
```

Be sure you have used class "answerButton" only for this submit button.

Hope so it will help you.